# All rows in a matrix equal

Tags: r

Im trying to get the command rows_equal to work but not managing to do so.

The matrix in question is:

```
P <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2,   0.3, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how large "n" has to be in P^n that will make all the rows in the matrix equal.

```
mpow <- function(P, n) {if (n == 0) {return(diag(nrow(P)))} else if 
                                           (n == 1) {return(P)} else {
                                            return(P %*% mpow(P, n - 1))} }

rows_equal <- function(P, d = 4) {P_new <- trunc(P * 10^d) 
                                  for (k in 2:nrow(P_new)) {if 
                                        (!all(P_new[1, ] == P_new[k, ])) {
                                               return(FALSE)} }
                                  return(TRUE) }
```

This is what I enter into Rstudio, however, I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Isn't the command rows_equal suppose to give us False or True?

Thank you for reading my question/
Confused student with a large headache.

Comment: Modify title to indicate your product name

Comment: The `%^%` function in package `expm` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from formatting, I made two changes to your code:

1. you forgot to use your `mpow` function and used `trunc(P * 10^d)` instead.
2. I replaced `==` with `all.equal`, which allows for some numerical imprecision.

Using `all.equal` to compare numerical values is typically preferable to `==` in these situations.

```
rows_equal <- function(P, d = 4) {
                P_new <- mpow(P, d)

                for (k in 2:nrow(P_new)) {
                if ((all.equal(P_new[1, ], P_new[k, ])) != TRUE) {
                  return(FALSE)
                }}
                return(TRUE)
              }
```

This outputs

```
> rows_equal(P, 10)
[1] FALSE
> rows_equal(P, 50)
[1] TRUE
```